# Custom attributes cannot inject in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I just want to implement custom attributes inject in spring boot.But it does 
not work well.
First, I create a annotation like below

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ConfigValue {
    String name();
}
```

Second,I create a config class with customize annotation like below

```
@Configuration
public class MysqlConf {
@Value("${spring.datasource.driverClassName}")
private String className;
@Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
private String jdbcUrl;
@Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
private String username;
@ConfigValue(name = "spring.datasource.password")
private String password;

@Bean
public DataSource druidDataSource() {
    DruidDataSource druidDataSource = new DruidDataSource();
    druidDataSource.setDriverClassName(className);
    druidDataSource.setUsername(username);
    druidDataSource.setPassword(password);
    druidDataSource.setUrl(jdbcUrl);
    druidDataSource.setMaxActive(20);
    druidDataSource.setInitialSize(1);
    druidDataSource.setMinIdle(1);
    druidDataSource.setMaxWait(60000);
    druidDataSource.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(60000);
    druidDataSource.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(300000);
    druidDataSource.setValidationQuery("select 1");
    druidDataSource.setTestWhileIdle(true);
    druidDataSource.setTestOnBorrow(false);
    druidDataSource.setTestOnReturn(false);
    druidDataSource.setPoolPreparedStatements(true);
    druidDataSource.setMaxPoolPreparedStatementPerConnectionSize(50);

    return druidDataSource;
 }
```

}

Then I set custom attributes like below

```
@Component
public class BeanPropertiesUtil  implements 
InitializingBean,BeanFactoryAware {

private static final Logger logger = 
LoggerFactory.getLogger(BeanPropertiesUtil.class);

private BeanFactory beanFactory;

public static Map<String,Object> configMap = new HashMap<>();

@PostConstruct
public void init() throws Exception {
   configMap.put("spring.datasource.password","123321");
   configMap.put("orderNo","2018051929991");
}

@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    logger.info("config map : "+ JSON.toJSONString(configMap));
    ApplicationContext applicationContext = 
        BeanNameUtil.getApplicationContext();
    final String[] beanDefinitionNames = 
        applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames();
    for(String beanName : beanDefinitionNames) {
        Object bean = beanFactory.getBean(beanName);
        final Field[] declaredFields = bean.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        if(declaredFields.length > 0) {
            for(Field field : declaredFields) {
                final ConfigValue configValue = 
                    field.getAnnotation(ConfigValue.class);
                if(configValue != null) {
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    logger.info("field name :"+field.getName() +" field 
                       value:"+configMap.get(configValue.name()));
                    field.set(bean,configMap.get(configValue.name()));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
    this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
}
```

}

It cannot get password value, I also create an other class

```
@Service
public class MyAnnotationService {

@ConfigValue(name = "spring.datasource.password")
private String password;

public void deSth() {
    System.err.println("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:"+password);
  }
}
```

it works,
I do not know why MysqlConf can't get the value but MyAnnotationService can.Please help me,Thanks!

Comment: Because the `@Component` is not available before the `@Configuration`.

Comment: Also why do you want to invent your own mechanism instead of using the defaults?

Comment: Thank you,I want to implement a configuration center instead of configuration files by zookeeper,so I connect to zookeeper first and down load the configs when the system stand up ,then I inject it to classes who marked my annotations.

Comment: Again why would you need to override the defaults for that. Create a `PropertySource` that knows how to handle that instead of bolting on another configuration solution.

Comment: PropertySource can not read properties from zookeeper.

Comment: Read my comment... Implement your own `PropertySource` which can do that... Yes it can read if you provide a `PropertySource` to read from ZooKeeper. I clearly said `PropertySource` NOT `@PropertySource` which basically refers to `ResourcePropertySource`. If you have your own `PropertySource` implementation you can register it with the `Environment` to have it applied just as the other `PropertySource`s. This is also what Spring Cloud Config does for obtaining properties from Github etc.

Comment: I see.I'll try.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bean.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
```

not returning fields for @Configuration MysqlConf class, it works if you change MysqlConf to @Service